# WordPress site gets white and screen and admin displays text only

Tags: wordpress

My wordpress site suddenly gets whitescreen on frontend withour displaying any error and admin displays text only, i tried to rollback to revert the last back up after i reverted it, it works fine, but after a couple of minutes(10-15min). it goes back to white screen again.

what should i do?

Comment: There are many reasons that could caused this, https://codex.wordpress.org/Common_WordPress_Errors will help you to isolate it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to enable:

```
('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

In wp-config.php file. It will help you see the error in the front-end of the website. Mostly white screen is related to server's exhausted memory.

But it's not only limited to that. For in depth checking such as the issue could be due to a plugin which is poorly coded or has deprecated piece of code in it, you need to enable in depth Debugging in **wp-config.php**

Add the following files in your wp-config.php file:

```
 // Enable WP_DEBUG mode
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );

// Enable Debug logging to the /wp-content/debug.log file
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );

// Disable display of errors and warnings 
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );

// Force Display Errors even if disabled in php directive
@ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );

// Use dev versions of core JS and CSS files (only needed if you are modifying these core files)
define( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG', true );
```

Once enabled, please try reloading the page, most of the time errors appear on the frontend and backend as well , but if you don't see anything, then you should head to **/wp-content/debug.log**, open that file with any text editor and you should be able to see exact cause of trouble.

For further explanation about WordPress errors and troubleshooting, read codex here:

`https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress`

If it doesn't work and nothing shows up then try using following approach:

Try renaming your plugins directory in **/wp-content/**, and see if website comes up.

If website loads, then there is a problem in plugins.

Once you see website coming up, rename again your plugins directory to what it was before and go to your website Database either in PHPMYADMIN or whatever app your hosting provides to manage DB, inside your database.

---> {YOUR WP DB} --> {wp_options} table.

In **wp_options** table, search for the following option name: **active_plugins**.

Click in the value field and remove the value from it. This will tell WP to de-activate all the plugins.

You can login to Backend (WP-Dashboard) and start activating plugins again and once doing it, make sure to keep refreshing Website's frontend, untill you find the root cause of trouble such as there will be a stage when Activating certain plugin will again cause this error, at that stage, you need to login to FTP, and rename that specific plugin from directory:

/plugins/{specific_plugin}   rename it to /plugins/{specific_plugin_2}

Your website will load, keep repeating the process unless you find how many plugins are causing this issue to happen.

Comment: hi thanks, i already did what you said, but it displays nothing no the front end, and my wp-content has no debug.log file

Comment: Alright, try renaming your plugins directory in /wp-content/, and see if website comes up. If website loads, then there is a problem in plugins.
Once you see website coming up, rename again your plugins directory to what it was before and go to phpmyadmin, inside your database. 

PHPMYADMIN   --->  {YOUR WP DB} --> {wp_options} table.

In wp_options table, search for the following option name: **active_plugins**.

Click in the value field and remove the value from it.

This will tell WP to de-activate all the plugins.

You can login to Backend and start activating plugins

Answer (score 0):

Put **ob_start();** in wp-config.php file

Answer (score 0):

Clear your browser's cache. If you use a network delivery service like Cloudflare, clear the cache there also.